# Internal database summation

Tags: mysql, database

So basically I have this table `Class_Sumations` where I need to come up with some way to calculate the sum of the `NumberofClassesTaken` and the `AmountPaid` columns from the other tables...into the respectful columns in the last table.

The `NumberofClassesTaken` column would just sum all the classes the Client took and give a number. The `AmountPaid` column would sum all the dollar amounts spent on classes by a given client and give a total.

So for example Client 1 could have taken 2 yoga classes and paid $200 total so the `NumberofClassesTaken` would show 2, and the `AmountPaid` column would show 100.

I tried doing `SELECT` and sum but I always get the

> Error code 1064, SQL state 42000: You have an error in your SQL syntax

thrown back at me.

Can anyone point me in the right direction here? (Keep in mind I'm relatively new to this so if you have some documentation to what you're suggesting that would be awesome too)

PS: I omitted the TRAINER table because it is a separate total from the club classes so you can ignore that foreign key in CLUB_CLASSES.

```
CREATE TABLE CLIENT(
  ClientNumber INT(50) NOT NULL, 
  ClientLastName VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, 
  ClientFirstName VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, 
  ClientPhone VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, 
  ClientEmail VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, 
  ClientState VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, 
  ClientCity VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, 
  ClientStreet VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, 
  ClientAddress VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, 
  ClientZipCode INT NOT NULL, 
  PRIMARY KEY (ClientNumber));

INSERT INTO CLIENT 
  VALUES    
    ('1','Marget','Michael','7703399207','MM@gmail.com',
     'Kentucky','Merlin','Wending Way','312 Wending Way','30144');
INSERT INTO CLIENT 
  VALUES 
    ('2','Squarepants','Spongebob','7701274532','SS@gmail.com',
     'Kentucky','Merlin','Pineapple Under the Sea Way', 
     '856 Pineapple Under the Seas Way','30122');

CREATE TABLE CLUB_CLASSES(
  ClassID INT(50) NOT NULL, 
  InstructorTrainerID INT(50) NOT NULL, 
  ClassName VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, 
  ClassStartDate date NOT NULL, 
  ClassEndDate date NOT NULL, 
  ClassCost VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, 
  PRIMARY KEY(ClassID), 
  FOREIGN KEY (InstructorTrainerID) REFERENCES TRAINER(TrainerID));

INSERT INTO CLUB_CLASSES 
  VALUES ('3501','1154','Yoga','1/3/13','1/5/13','100');
INSERT INTO CLUB_CLASSES 
  VALUES ('3502','2856','Pillate','1/3/13','2/5/13','50');

CREATE TABLE CLASS_SUMMATIONS(
  ClassID INT(50) NOT NULL, 
  ClientID INT(50) NOT NULL, 
  NumberofClassesTaken VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, 
  AmountPaid VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, 
  PRIMARY KEY(ClassID, ClientNumber), 
  FOREIGN KEY(ClientNumber) REFERENCES CLIENT(ClientNumber));

INSERT INTO CLIENT_SUMMATIONS (
  '3501','1',
  'SELECT SUM(CLUB_CLASSES.ClassID','SELECT SUM(CLUB_CLASSES.ClassCost)');
INSERT INTO CLIENT_SUMMATIONS('3502','2','xxx','xxxx');
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show what you've tried so far that isn't working for you. There's no `SELECT` in any of what you've posted here. Thanks.

Comment: There are way too many errors in your SQL to even try to answer it. There's no column width on an `INT` column, especially an `INT(50)` - what would a 50-digit integer value represent as a ClassID? You have foreign keys on columns that don't exist. You have invalid `SUM` use where you need `COUNT`, and you've quoted your `SELECT` when it's not a quoted string (it's a separate SQL statement) and have no `FROM <table>` in your `SELECT` anyway, and you'd need a `GROUP BY` in order to use `COUNT` or `SUM`. Both `INSERT`s could be a single `SELECT`. A SQL tutorial might help; these are basics.